# Why is this.state.name not being used properly in my component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs-flux, reactjs

I have a `teamName` store that stores the name of the team and changes on depending on whether a name is clicked/hovered.

**TeamStore.js:**

```
function setName(name) {
    _team = name;
    _original = name;
}

//set a temp team name when sidemenu item is being hovered
function setHover(team) {
    _original = _team;
    _team = team;
}

function removeHover() {
    //console.log(_original);
    _team = _original;
}
```

I also have `ThumbNail.jsx` that listens to this store and triggers an `_updateArticle` method when `this.state.name` changes. However, its not working properly.

- the articles don't change when the item is being hovered.
- the articles change to the hovered item on hover leave (which they shouldn't) they should go back to original one that was clicked.

**ThumbNail.jsx:**

```
var ThumbNail = React.createClass({
    mixins: [ReactFireMixin],

    getTeamState() {
        return  TeamStore.getSelected() ;
    },

    getInitialState() {
        return {
            name: this.getTeamState(),
            articles: []
                };
    },

    getDefaultProps() {
        return {
            baseUrl: "https://shining-inferno-1085.firebaseio.com/"
        }
    },


    _updateArticle() {
        //console.log(this.state.name);
        var teamRef = new Firebase(this.props.baseUrl + this.state.name + "/results");

        this.bindAsArray(teamRef, 'articles');

    },

    componentDidMount() {

        TeamStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
        this._updateArticle();
    },

    componentWillUnmount() {
        TeamStore.removeChangeListener(this._onChange);
        this.unbind("articles");
    },

    render() {

        return (

            <ul className="tiles">
                <BasicInfo article={this.state.articles} />
            </ul>
            )   
    },

    _onChange() {
        var team = this.getTeamState();
        this.setState({name: team});
        //console.log(this.props.baseUrl + this.state.name + "/results");
        this.unbind("articles");
        this._updateArticle();
    }


});


module.exports = ThumbNail;
```

P.S I have a title component that listens to the same store and works fine. Let me know if you need that.

**Edit:** Care to explain the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem could be similar to **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32303069/this-state-foo-is-different-in-onchange-and-different-in-render/32303903#32303903)**.

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value.

Comment: ha! just noticed. it is you who asked the other question as well :)

Comment: haha yes, I wasn't getting any response so I assumed I had worded this poorly