# this.state.foo is different in _onChange and different in render()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs-flux, reactjs

In `_onChange` method, I wait for a change in `this.state.name`. On the change `_updateArticle` method is called:

```
_onChange() {

        var team = this.getTeamState();
        this.setState({name: team});
        console.log(this.state.name); //"Boston Celtics" //this should have changed but it didn't 
        this.unbind("articles");
        this._updateArticle();
    },
```

then in _updateArticle a new reference is created using this new state.

```
_updateArticle(team) {
        var teamRef = new Firebase(this.props.baseUrl + team + "/results");
        console.log(this.state.team); // "Boston Celtics" //this should have been new but its not
        this.bindAsArray(teamRef, 'articles');

    },
```

In `render` method however just to check the state I put `console.log` to check. In `render`, `this.state.name` has been updated properly. My question is **why is `this.state` different outside of `render` function?**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the **[API docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate)**:

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value.

If you really want to access `state` right after calling `setState`, use the callback parameter in the `setState` method:

> setState(function|object nextState[, function callback])

So your code should look like:

```
_onChange() {
  var team = this.getTeamState();
  this.setState({name: team}, function() {
    console.log(this.state.name);
    this.unbind("articles");
    this._updateArticle(this.state.team);
  });
}
```

Hope this helps.